# Функция проверка не пуста ли таблица?

Tags: php, mysql

Эта функция возвращает всегда 1 (TRUE), может есть получше варианты узнать пуста ли таблица?

```
function isEmpty($tableName)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tableName";
    $q = mysql_query($sql);
    if (mysql_num_rows==0)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

echo isEmpty("mytable");
```

Comment: Что есть mysql_num_rows? Она вроде раньше функцией была?

Comment: да, спасибо, вполне логично, а echo FALSE выводит как ноль или вообще ничего не выводит?

Comment: False будет как ноль, если тебе нужно ничего то используй null.

Comment: ну не знаю у меня echo FALSE выводит вообще ничего, пустоту, не 0 и не null.

Comment: хотя если так: if (FALSE==null){echo "TRUE";} else echo "FALSE"; или if (FALSE==0){echo "TRUE";} else echo "FALSE"; то все правильно, ну ладно, спасибо, это я уже так, от темы отошел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function isEmpty($table){
 $db=new PDO('$dsn', '$user', '$password');
 $req=$db->prepare("select table_rows from information_schema.tables where table_name=?");
 $req->execute(array($table));
 return $req->fetchColumn()?false:true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

У тебя ошибка в строке if (mysql_num_rows==0) долно быть if (mysql_num_rows($q)==0)

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйся предикатой  SQL EXISTS, у нее единственный параметр подзапрос, если подзапрос возвращает любое результирующие множество EXISTS возвращает TRUE.

Comment: А возможно ли этой предикатой воспользоваться в MySQLi? Хотелось бы пример увидеть, а пока по доках пройдусь.